# Replace empty column with other column value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-connector

I would like to display the "Actual_Data" table on PHP if there is any value, but if it's empty i would like to display the "Estimated_Date" value.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmWBI.png)

I have tried entering ISNULL and other features but then it doesn't display anything anymore. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBhog.png)

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how not to use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors

Answer (score 1):

[`ISNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) returns boolean. You need [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(Actual_Date, Estimated_date) FROM orderstracking WHERE OrderID = :orderId
```

Comment: Tried this, but still the same problem, it doesn't display anything on the page.

Comment: @MaGnuuSa How about you edit your question with actual code that you have (sql and php)